# Need to create google map with markers from json file on backbone.js

Tags: html, google-maps, backbone.js, google-maps-markers

I need to do a google map with markers from json file on backbone.js.
Here is backbone js code. Map is loaded. 
I need to load a markers from json file.
I haven't see the markers at all. I am a beginner in backbone. Please help me.

```
(function($) {
var Map = Backbone.Model.extend({})
var MapView = Backbone.View.extend({    
    initialize: function(opts) {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.render();
    this.markers();
    },
    render: function() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.model.get('latitude'), this.model.get('longitude'));
        var options = {
            zoom: 6,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };  
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.el, options);           
        return this;
    },      
    markers: function() {
        $.ajax({ 
          'async': true, 
          'global': false, 
          'url': "file:///D:/Work/Done/js/data1.json", 
          'dataType': "json", 
          'success': function (data) {
          console.log('MAP');
            for (var i = 0, length = data.length; i < length; i++) {
              var item = data[i];
              var latLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(item.latLon.lat, item.latLon.lon); 
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng2,
                map: map,
                title: 'Hello World!'
              });
            } 
          }
        });   
        var map = this.map;         
        return this;
    }
}); 
var map = new Map({
    latitude: "55.660058",
    longitude: "12.521015",
})
var map_view = new MapView({
    el: $('.map')[0],
    model: map,
});
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly do this, no need of ajax call.

var roads = ;

Use that in the loop.

Var Markers = '';

for (var j=0; j < ; j++){roads[j]['latutude'];}

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

there is two problems with the code:

1. You are never calling the function that makes the AJAX call. You assign the function to the `json` variable, but never call it.
2. You can't return the result of an asynchronous call from the function. The function will return before the result has arrived.

Don't put the code in a function that you don't use. Create the markers in the callback of the AJAX call, where the result exists:

```
$.ajax({ 
  'async': true, 
  'global': false, 
  'url': "file:///D:/Work/Done/Valtech/js/data1.json", 
  'dataType': "json", 
  'success': function (data) {
    for (var i = 0, length = data.length; i < length; i++) {
      var item = data[i],
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(item.latLon.lat, item.latLon.lon); 
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
      });
    } 
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Guffa,I have tried but still doesn't work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Julia: What happens when you try it? Do you get any error message?

Comment: I don't see any markers on map.. without the errors..Maybe I need to create some collection for markers

Comment: @Julia: You don't need a collection for the markers, they are associated with the map by setting the `map` property. But you have to assign the map object to the variable `map` that is used in the code for the markers.

Comment: @Julia: Use `var map = this.map;` efter you have created the map object.

Comment: Hi Guffa, Where put this code? Actually I need to show the markers when I click the link. I have three links with 3 json files. When I click each links show markers which related to this json file...

Comment: @Julia: Put that code right after the line where you create the map object and assign it to `this.map`. To load different markers you would put the code that adds the markers in a separate method, so that you can call it. If you use a parameter for the file to load, you only need one method to load any of the files.

Comment: Guffa I changed the code but still doesn't work. What wrong with this? I have updated code in the top.

Comment: @Julia: You are trying to use the map before you create it. Swap the calls to `render` and `markers` in `initialize`.

Comment: Do you see "MAP" in the console?

Comment: @Julia: Then you don't even get a response from the AJAX call. Determine if the `markers` method is actually called, check the network log to see if there is an AJAX request, check the response to see if it looks as expected.

Comment: Hi Guffa, Could you please show how it will be in a code. I understand on theory but difficult to do this on practise.

Comment: @Julia: Put a `console.log` or an `alert` first in the method to see if it is called at all, or start the debugger and set a breakpoint.